# Div block to responsively go up as the windows gets narrower

Tags: css, responsive-design

Now, when i make the window of my codepen narrower, the block with quote responsively goes down, covering both buttons.

- I would like it to go up so it doesn't approach the buttons.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/RycerzPegaza/pen/NGpEGp?editors=010

Here's the CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Amatic+SC:700&subset=latin,latin-ext);

body{
  background: url('http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r293/VIEWLINER/REED/RFGF02.jpg~original') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}


.row-fluid {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}


p {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 250%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#qouteblock {

  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: ;
}

#background{
  position: relative;
  top: 170px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}


.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 46%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

iframe {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 46%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries for reduce font-size propierty of .content:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
 p {
  font-size: 30px
 }
}
```